# Add Spring Boot to existing hibernate - embedded derby application

Tags: spring, hibernate, derby

I already have an existing application with hibernate and embedded derby working.
My hibernate.cfg.xml has the following settings

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby:data;create=true</property>
<property name="connection.username">application</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>

<property name="hibernate.default_schema">my_application</property>
```

everything has been working fine but I wish to add spring boot to that project and I am getting

> Failed to create sessionFactory
>   object.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create
>   requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

when I am loading the sessionFactory from hibernate. Why can I not do that? Is loading embedded Derby from spring boot the only way? I don't want spring boot to have any relation to the database.

Also, after adding spring boot my log4j.properties file is not read anymore even if I do not run spring boot at all.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. needed to set application.properties like this

> spring.jpa.show-sql=true spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
>   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
>
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:data;create=true
>   spring.datasource.username=application
>   spring.datasource.password=password
>   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
>
> spring.datasource.initialize=true
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

my boot app needs a hibernate bean like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("core.peristence.dtos")
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

and my service can autowire the sessionFactory now like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

...

}
```